# How to make a Custom Carousell flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Found this on cool carousell UI on
[dribble](https://dribbble.com/shots/15248148-Cinema-App-P1/attachments/6997615?mode=media)

I really wanted to make something like this but don't know where to start

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!!

[image: fafa]

Comment: take a look at `ListWheelScrollView`

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
You can design your card the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily with cuasual package, or you can also achieve it by using `PageView`.

Here is an example:

- **PageView**: show 1 page and see the previous/next page by setting *viewportFraction*
- **AnimatedBuilder**: listen to the change of page offset
- **Transform**: scale, rotate and translation the position of next, previous page

code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

const viewportFraction = 0.7;

class MyPageView extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPageView({
    required this.children,
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final List<Widget> children;

  factory MyPageView.images(List<ImageProvider> imageProviders) {
    return MyPageView(
      children: [
        for (final image in imageProviders)
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            child: Image(
              image: image,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  State<MyPageView> createState() => _MyPageViewState();
}

class _MyPageViewState extends State<MyPageView> {
  final pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: viewportFraction);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraint) {
        final maxWidth = constraint.maxWidth;
        return PageView.builder(
          allowImplicitScrolling: true,
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: widget.children.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            final child = widget.children[index];
            return AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: pageController,
              builder: (_, __) {
                final ratioX = pageController.offset / maxWidth / viewportFraction - index;

                return Transform.rotate(
                  angle: math.pi * -0.05 * ratioX,
                  child: Transform.translate(
                    offset: Offset(ratioX * 10, ratioX.abs() * 70),
                    child: Transform.scale(
                      scale: 0.8,
                      child: child,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

And here is the example result:

```
MyPageView.images(
  List.generate(
    50,
     (index) => NetworkImage('https://picsum.photos/seed/$index/400/600'),
    ),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks! Will definitely study this!

Answer (score 0):

You could play with the values of a ListView with horizontal axis and apply some animations. However there is already a packages that fits perfect to make that effect: https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper

Answer (score -1):

you can make it with editing in Carousel Slider Package files and save your edits in `.pubcache`to get it with pub get. This is the better solution